# Get Folder Name from Uri using SAF

Tags: android, storage-access-framework

I am using SAF where user is allowed to select directory/folder and then i would like to display its name in Textview once selected. I used below code to start intent.

```
  Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE);
                startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
```

and below code is for onActivityResult

```
  if (resultCode == RESULT_OK && requestCode == 1) {
    DocumentFile documentFile = DocumentFile.fromTreeUri(this, uriTree);

            textInfo.append(documentFile .getName() + "\n");

        }
```

Changed question as per guidance, it is returning foldername now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `DocumentFile.fromTreeUri()` to get a `DocumentFile` on the tree `Uri` that you are getting in `onActivityResult()`. Then, call `getName()` on the `DocumentFile` to get a display name associated with that tree.